# How can I add values only if "x" is present?

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm working on adding a collection of board games to our library.

I have a spreadsheet that lists more games than I intend to buy, but have them there to investigate. I have the prices for a couple of websites listed beside each game.

The problem is that I want a sum that doesn't include every game on the list. Instead, I want to add a column at the front that if I put an "X" indicating this is a game to get, then I want it to add the value for that. Only the values for rows that start with an "X" in column A will in added together, instead of everything.

I was hoping to do this with a formula instead of just choosing a basic `=SUM` formula and selecting only a few cells at a time. I assume a `=SUMIF` might be the answer, but I have yet to figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: Try using the `COUNTIF` and `SUMIF` formulas and experiment with them to get you started. SO is here to help solve specific issues, not help you do your research.

Comment: @pnuts I just get real lazy when people don't seem to put forth much effort on understanding functions that are *well documented*. I do believe in the SO philosophy of Good SO Questions will receive Good SO Answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"x",B:B)
```

where B:B is the column with the values. I suspect your difficulty may have been that when using text as the 'trigger' it needs to be in double inverted commas.

Or you might sort by ColumnA and just use =SUM as far down as there are `x`s.

Or filter on ColumnA to select `x` and Autosum ColumnB but change the `9` to `109`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIF` requires at least 2 parameters, and at most 3. In your case, you will need to use 3.

If you type the formula in excel, you will see a little balloon indicating:

```
=SUMIF(Range, Criteria, [Sum_Range])
```

`Range` is the range where you want to apply the condition, in your case, `A:A`.

`Criteria` is the condition applied to the range, in your case `"x"`.

`[Sum_Range]` is the range to sum, after applying the condition.

The above will sum all the cells in the range `[Sum_Range]`, for which the cells of `Range` satisfies the condition `Criteria`.

Translating that into an actual formula, you get pnut's formula:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"x",B:B)
```

The above will sum all the cells in the range `B:B`, for which the cells of `A:A` satisfies the condition `x` (`SUMIF` considers the criterion as being 'equal' so it will sum only when they are equal to the criteria).

---

As an extra, you can change the condition to mean 'not equal' by using something like this: `=SUMIF(A:A,"<>x",B:B)` (the `<>` means not equal to in Excel).